# Angular 2 unit testing with material icons and images

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript

I have implemented the component depicted below which uses an image, material icons, and a custom `ticker` directive that scrolls either line of text if it is too long for the element.

[image]

Now I'm trying to learn unit testing using karma (via angular cli/webpack) and I have the majority of the configuration figured out to create the component, but I'm struggling to understand how to configure for images, material icons, and get the directive `HostListener` to work.

Here is what I have created so far:

[image]

```
/* config */
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TickerDirective } from '../../directives/ticker.directive';
import { MdIconModule, MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MdIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';

/* my stuff */
import { FoodListComponent } from './food-list.component';
import { FoodDataService } from '../../services/food-items/food-data.service';
import { FoodItem } from '../../diet/food-item';
import { WorkingData } from '../../services/working-data/working-data';
import { WorkingDataService } from '../../services/working-data/working-data.service';

describe('FoodListComponent', () => {
  let component:          FoodListComponent;
  let fixture:            ComponentFixture<FoodListComponent>;
  let foodDataService:    FoodItem[];
  let workingDataService: WorkingData;
  let de:                 DebugElement[];
  let el:                 HTMLElement;

  /* Stub Services */
  let foodDataServiceStub = [{
    name: 'test food name ..................', // written long to trigger the ticker directive
    img: './no_image.png',
    description: 'test food description'
  }];

  let workingDataServiceStub = {
    today: new Date(),
    selectedDate: new Date(2016, 2, 5),
    targetDate: new Date(2016, 2, 7),
    data: {exercise: 'Squat'}
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ FoodListComponent, TickerDirective ],
      imports: [ MaterialModule.forRoot(), MdIconModule], // not sure if this is correct
      providers: [
        { provide: FoodDataService, useValue: foodDataServiceStub },
        { provide: WorkingDataService, useValue: workingDataServiceStub } ,
        MdIconRegistry // not sure if this is correct
      ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FoodListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    /* Inject services */
    foodDataService = TestBed.get(FoodDataService);
    workingDataService = TestBed.get(WorkingDataService);

    /* Assign Services */
    component.workingData = workingDataService;
    component.foods = foodDataService;

    fixture.detectChanges();
    de = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('span'));
    el = de[0].nativeElement;
    // console.log(el);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('should have the correct food name', () => {
    expect(el.textContent).toContain('test food name ..................');
  });
});
```

**Image**
I have a png 'no_image.png' in the same folder as the `spec.ts` file. It seems to locate the image because there is no 404 error (as it did when I put in a wrong path), but the image is not rendered.

**Ticker Directive**
The ticker renders the correct `span` so it seems to set up the ticker properly, but the the `HostListener` doesn't seem to pick up on the mouseover event to trigger the directve action. I tried importing `HostListener` into `TestBed` but that through an error.

**Material Icons**
You can see the ligatures of the material icons, but they are not rendering. I read that I needed to import `Http` but that through an error.

Help in implementing any or all of these would be greatly appreciated, but I would also like to hear how I could go about problem solving these kinds of issues in the future (my google searches did not yield helpful results).

Comment: ops, sorry man, I didn't see the date of your post, so I think you are the god of test now;)

Answer (score 3):

you don't have so high-level logic in this component and you can not writ so big `unit test`, for that component actually `integration` test is usable, so you can test the `value`, `color`, `size` of your component.

> **INTEGRATION TESTING**  is a level of software testing where individual units are combined and tested as a group. The purpose of
>   this level of testing is to expose faults in the interaction between
>   integrated units. Test drivers and test stubs are used to assist in
>   Integration Testing.

[read more](http://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/integration-testing/)

Comment: Thanks, yeah this is more of an e2e type of tests. Unit tests are much more granular. I could also add the icon module and host the images, but that's unnesseary